# Calculate sum of column in table(no sql)

Tags: php, html, sum

I have a table which holds four headers

```
Module
Mark
Grade
GPA Mark
```

They ask the user to input marks and store them in a variable which goes through a while loop to decide the Grade ( A,B,C,D) and the GPA mark is the same function as well.

My last query is: I want to calculate average of GPA mark ( out of 4 ) for 5 modules been entered and graded for the user.

I tried to use for loop:

```
<?php function Sum($Getgpa)
   { 
    for (int i = 0; i < array[$Getgpa].length; i++)
       return Sum/5;
   }
?>
```

but returns error, as I want to display the average in the bottom of the GPA column.
Please help ?

Comment: Your code is not php.

Comment: sorry forgot to add the tags

Comment: unclear what you are asking and tried code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easily you can use "array_sum" and "count" function to your class and catch your result dynamically.

```
  <?php
  function Sum($Getgpa)
  {
      return array_sum($Getgpa)/count($Getgpa);
  }
      $Getgpa = array(5, 10, 15, 30, 12);
      echo Sum($Getgpa); 
  ?>
```

Comment: <?php
    function Sum($Getgpa)
    {
    return array_sum($Getgpa)/count($Getgpa);
    }
    $Getgpa =     array(Getgpa($_REQUEST['mod1']),Getgpa($_REQUEST['mod2']),Getgpa($_REQUEST['mod3']),Getgpa($_REQUEST['mod4']),Getgpa($_REQUEST['mod5']));
      echo Sum($Getgpa); 
  ?>

Comment: I updated your code with my dynamic results and it worked perfectly ! Thanks alot ! sir !

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't name your function sum if it calculates an average. Call it average.

```
function average($Getgpa)
{ 
    return array_sum($Getgpa) / count($Getgpa);
}
```

or closer to your attempt :

```
function average($Getgpa)
{
    $sum = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($Getgpa); $i++)
        $sum += $Getgpa[$i];
    return $sum / count($Getgpa);
}
```

Comment: This is an example of of row  '<tr>
    <td>module 5</td>
    <td><?php echo $_REQUEST['mod5'] ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo GetGrade($_REQUEST['mod5']) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo Getgpa($_REQUEST['mod5']) ?></td>
    </tr>'

Comment: @user38 What means your comment ? Do you know ANYTHING about php ? Read at least an introductory tutorial before asking here.

Comment: Thank you for your ' mini ' lecture :)